# Excel VBA Target.address worksheet.onchange infinite loop

Tags: excel, onchange, vba

I have cell A1, cell B1 and cell C1, I need check if value changed in A1 by user or by VBA. Whith out If statment on Target.Address A1 makes infinite loop

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As range)

If Target.Address = B1 or Target.Address = C1 Then
    If IsEmpty(Cell("B1")) then
        Cell("A1").value = "Enter value"
            If IsEmpty(Cell("C1")) then
                Cell("A1").value = ""
            Else
                Cell("A1").value = "=C1/B1"
            End IF
    End IF
End IF


If Target.Address = A1
    IF "changed by user typing" Then
       Cell("B1").value = ""
       Cell("C1").value = ""
    Else
    End IF
End IF
End Sub
```

How to determine what Target was changed by user not from VBA?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect you want something like this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A1")) Is Nothing Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Range("B1:C1").Value = ""
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    ElseIf Not Intersect(Target, Range("B1:C1")) Is Nothing Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        If IsEmpty(Range("B1")) Then
            Range("A1").Value = "Enter value"
        ElseIf IsEmpty(Range("C1")) Then
            Range("A1").Value = ""
        Else
            Range("A1").Value = "=C1/B1"
        End If
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Yes but I need to do that only if change makes in specified cell If `Target.Address = B1 or Target.Address = C1 Then`
 `If Target.Address = A1 Then`

Comment: That doesn't make sense - the target address can't be both. The code I posted will clear B1:C1 if the user changes A1 or follow your original logic if the user changes B1 or C1. Please test it and _then_ tell me if it doesn't do what you need.

Comment: Error on Range("B1:C1").Value = ""
Method value of object Range Failed

Comment: Is the sheet protected? I tested the code before posting it and it works for me.

Comment: Sheet is not protected, but have a lot of code on worksheet.change wich works well without that code, but if i post that code i get error

Comment: I think it because infinite loop on range exist !!!
`If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A1")) Is Nothing Then 
Range("B1:C1").Value = ""

 ANd If IsEmpty(Range("B1")) Then
Range("A1").Value = "Enter value"

`
go to infinite redirects each others as worksheet is changed.

Comment: Your code also do infinite loop
Try insert msgbox "Infinite loop" after worksheet.onchange

Comment: My code disables events so there will be no recursion. I can't comment on code you haven't posted.